# DataGridView flickering issue

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView.but i am suffering from a flickering issue of the dgvw ! The dgvw is coded as follows:

```
   Private Sub userdatagrid_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles userdatagrid.DataBindingComplete
    userdatagrid.Columns(0).ReadOnly = False : userdatagrid.Columns(2).ReadOnly = True
End Sub
Private Sub userdatagrid_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles userdatagrid.RowPrePaint
    For i = 0 To userdatagrid.Rows.Count - 1
        If userdatagrid.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = True Then
            userdatagrid.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(250, 187, 187)
        Else
            userdatagrid.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Azure
        End If
    Next
End Sub

    Private Sub userdatagrid_CellMouseEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles userdatagrid.CellMouseEnter
    If e.RowIndex > -1 Then
        userdatagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(233, 233, 233)
    Else
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub userdatagrid_CellMouseLeave(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles userdatagrid.CellMouseLeave
    If e.RowIndex > -1 Then
        userdatagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Azure
    End If
End Sub


    Private Sub filterdata(valuetosearch As String)
    Dim srq As String = "Select * from Contacts where CONCAT([Unique id],Prefix,[First name],[Last name],Gender,Title,Company,Phone,Mobile,Fax,[Business Email],[Personal email],Reference,Address,[Address 2],Country,City,Zip,Facebook,GooglePlus,Instagram,Twitter,Website,Salary,Currency,[Group],[Id/Status],Note,[Added by]) like '%" & valuetosearch & "%' "
    Dim mycmd As New SqlCommand(srq, con)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(mycmd)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    userdatagrid.DataSource = table
End Sub


   Private Sub DataGridView_CellChecked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    Dim dataGridView As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    If Not Me._IsSelectAllChecked Then
        If dataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = False Then
            'When any single CheckBox is unchecked, uncheck the header CheckBox.
            DirectCast(dataGridView.Controls.Item("SelectAll"), CheckBox).Checked = False
        Else
            'When any single CheckBox is checked, loop through all CheckBoxes to determine
            'if the header CheckBox needs to be unchecked.
            Dim isAllChecked As Boolean = True
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView.Rows
                If row.Cells(0).Value = False Then
                    isAllChecked = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            DirectCast(dataGridView.Controls.Item("SelectAll"), CheckBox).Checked = isAllChecked
        End If
    End If
End Sub

'The CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event happens after user change the cell value,
'before the cell lose focus and CellValueChanged event.
Private Sub DataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim dataGridView As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    If TypeOf dataGridView.CurrentCell Is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell Then
        'When the value changed cell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell, commit the change
        'to invoke the CellValueChanged event.
        dataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub AddSelectAllCheckBox(ByVal theDataGridView As DataGridView)
    Dim cbx As New CheckBox
    cbx.Name = "SelectAll"
    'The box size
    cbx.Size = New Size(14, 14)

    Dim rect As Rectangle
    rect = theDataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(25, -1, True)
    'Put CheckBox in the middle-center of the column header.
    'cbx.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(rect.Location.X + ((rect.Width - cbx.Width / 2)), rect.Location.Y + ((rect.Height - cbx.Height) / 2))
    cbx.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(rect.Location.X + 17, rect.Location.Y + 15)
    cbx.BackColor = Color.White
    theDataGridView.Controls.Add(cbx)

    'Handle header CheckBox check/uncheck function
    AddHandler cbx.Click, AddressOf HeaderCheckBox_Click
    'When any CheckBox value in the DataGridViewRows changed,
    'check/uncheck the header CheckBox accordingly.
    AddHandler theDataGridView.CellValueChanged, AddressOf DataGridView_CellChecked
    'This event handler is necessary to commit new CheckBox cell value right after
    'user clicks the CheckBox.
    'Without it, CellValueChanged event occurs until the CheckBox cell lose focus
    'which means the header CheckBox won't display corresponding checked state instantly when user
    'clicks any one of the CheckBoxes.
    AddHandler theDataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged, AddressOf DataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
End Sub


   Private _IsSelectAllChecked As Boolean
Private Sub HeaderCheckBox_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    For i = 0 To userdatagrid.Rows.Count - 1
        Me._IsSelectAllChecked = True
        Dim cbx As CheckBox
        cbx = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
        Dim theDataGridView As DataGridView = cbx.Parent
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In theDataGridView.Rows
            row.Cells(0).Value = cbx.Checked
        Next
        theDataGridView.EndEdit()
        Me._IsSelectAllChecked = False
        userdatagrid.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Azure
    Next
End Sub

 Private Sub Contact_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from contacts", con)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim table As New DataTable
    adapter.Fill(table)
    userdatagrid.DataSource = table
    userdatagrid.Columns(0).Frozen=true
    AddSelectAllCheckBox(userdatagrid)
    userdatagrid.Columns(0).Width = 48
    userdatagrid.Columns(1).Width = 33
    Dim img As DataGridViewImageColumn
    img = userdatagrid.Columns(1)
    img.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
```

What i have tried later :

```
 Private Sub userdatagrid_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles userdatagrid.RowPrePaint
    If e.RowIndex < 0 OrElse userdatagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then Return
    If Convert.ToInt32(userdatagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value) > False Then
        userdatagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(250, 187, 187)
    Else
        userdatagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Azure
    End If
End Sub
```

no luck
The dgvw has a lot of data in it as it's connected to a sql database...Earlier i had a flickering issue while a row's checkbox is checked..i fixed it...but now there is another problem...as mentioned, it has a lot of data.The problem is, while scrolling , the dgvw flickers a lot,.....any fixes? the solutions i found on the web suggested to create a new dgvw class which includes the  DOUBLEBUFFED property, but i don't want to do it, because i have made a lot of changes in the CELLSTYLE and ROWSTYLE of my current dgvw, any other fix without creating a new dgvw class?

P.S. my dgvw has a lot of RGB color variations, i mean it's colorful(don't know if it'll help but still included)

Comment: Rather than using the Paint event and looping thru every row, use the cell formatting evert or row prepaint and paint just the row the control is telling you needs to be painted

Comment: Thank you,this fixed it! But have another problem, my dgvw has a lots of data in it,while scrolling , there are also some flickerings...anyway to fix it ?

Comment: Probably more code doing more than it needs to - hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: sir, i found this code in CODEPROJECT,this is a c# code, can u please convert it for me to VB.net ....the code is 
....
....
public static void DoubleBuffered(this DataGridView dgv, bool setting) 
{ 
    Type dgvType = dgv.GetType(); 
    PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", 
          BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); 
    pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null); 
}

Comment: You dont need that - fix the *actual* problem by painting just what is needed in the appropriate event.

Comment: i fixed the problem i stated in the post but there are some flickering issues while scrolling the dgvw, so i searched google,found the code

Comment: the code is(converted using TELERIK) ...this is how it looks.......<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Shared Sub DoubleBuffered(dgv As DataGridView, setting As Boolean)
 Dim dgvType As Type = dgv.[GetType]()
 Dim pi As PropertyInfo = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
 pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, Nothing)
End Sub

but i get error in the <system.runtime>line and PROPERTYINFO and BINDINGFLAGS are not declared...what i should do ? and where do i put the <system.runtime>line of code?

Comment: *you dont need it*  A DGV can have 10s of thousands of rows colored according to some value somewhere and *not flicker*.  You have more code somewhere doing things the wrong way.  That code, if it works, hides the problem rather than fixes it

Comment: sir,please re-read the post, i've edited it

Comment: Please ***study*** the duplicate link - your code is causing the flicker.  Do not loop thru all the rows in the `RowPrePaint` (and CellFormatting may be the right one in this case) - you are processing rows that are not even showing!  In either case paint just the one that the event is requesting a paint job for - `e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs`.  I've said it 5 times now - at least try it.

Comment: sir i am currently a student so don't really know that much, can u please tell me where am i coding wrong ?

Comment: The duplicate link walks you thru it - study it.

Comment: sir....in the link there's a line as a solution : Convert.ToInt32(dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value) > 3

now here i change cells(3)to cells(0), my cell0 is a checkbox cell,so it's vlaue has to be either TRUE or FALSE, how do i add TRUE to the following line of code...i tried value>true but no luck

Comment: i did this : 

 Private Sub userdatagrid_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles userdatagrid.RowPrePaint
        If e.RowIndex < 0 OrElse userdatagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then Return
        If Convert.ToInt32(userdatagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value) > False Then
            userdatagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(250, 187, 187)
        Else
            userdatagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Azure
        End If
    End Sub

But the flickering still occures

Comment: I cant read that.  To convert to Boolean, just use `Convert.ToBoolean`.  If it is still flickering, you have other code somewhere causing it.  It also looks like that CellMouseEnter and Leave code will conflict - whats the point of that?

Comment: as suggested in the duplicate, i added e.rowindex in the cellmousenter and leave event...still the flickering is happening

Comment: Private Sub userdatagrid_CellMouseEnter
        If e.RowIndex > -1 Then
            userdatagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(233, 233, 233)
        Else
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub userdatagrid_CellMouseLeave(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles userdatagrid.CellMouseLeave
        If e.RowIndex > -1 Then
            userdatagrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Azure
        End If
    End Sub


.....DO u think they are causing it ?

Comment: Dont post code in comments - it doesnt format and is too hard to read.  Is it flickering in the exact same way?  You likely have another silly loop in some other event.  That CellMouseLeave looks wrong since it isnt changing it to the same color as the cellformatting event.

Comment: i don't get it...there's no code in the cell formatting event, so what then? but i do have code in the rowprepaint event...and yes,cellmouseleave and rowprepaint have the same color...so what is causing it ? i have posted all the codes that are related to my dgvw in the post...so please for once, tell me what am i doing wrong ? i followed the duplicate's solution but no luck